# tomcat's JNDI sharing

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

I have `tomcat` and `JNDI` point in system.

I need to use this point for connecting remote consumers. I read that tomcat doesn't share its `JNDI`, if so, how to set up a separate `JNDI` server on my network or is there any way to configure tomcat to share `JNDI`?

Comment: Among N computers in the network

Comment: Please use code tags for specifying tools and technologies.Please question after checking the result below in the screen and please visit help center for more.I have replace ` to ' used by mistake in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a 'JNDI server'. JNDI is a client-side API that interfaces to various naming technologies.

You could consider an LDAP server.